# Build and deploy my own docker image to the production server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I propably have missed something. So, I have installed docker on the production server and I have have a running application locally. It starts and runs on docker-compose.

So I feel like I am almost ready for deployment.

No I'd like to build a docker image and deploy it to the to the production server.

But when I try to build the image from the docker compose files like this

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose.production.yml build myapp
```

I keep getting **ERROR: No such service: app**

I haven't found any documentation the docker site, where the image build procedure from multiple dock-compose files is described. Maybe it's there, but then I have missed it.

My other Problem i.e. question is: where would I place the image tar(.gz) files on the target server.

Can I specify the target location for the images in either the **/etc/docker/daemon.json** or some other configuration file?

I simply don't know where to dump the image file on the production server.

Again, maybe there is some documentation somewhere on the docker web site. But if so, then I've missed that too.

**Addendum source files**

I was asked to add my docker-compose files to provide a running example. So, here's the entire code for development and production environments.

For the sake of simplicity, I've kept this example quite basic:

**Dockerfile.base**

```sh
# joint settings for development, production and staging
FROM mariadb:10.3
```

**Dockerfile.production**

```sh
# syntax = edrevo/dockerfile-plus
INCLUDE+ Dockerfile.base
# add more production specific settings when needed
```

**Dockerfile.development**

```sh
# syntax = edrevo/dockerfile-plus
INCLUDE+ Dockerfile.base
# add more production specific settings when needed
```

**docker-compose.base.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: my_mariadb
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./../../databases/mysql-my:/var/lib/mysql
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
    logging:
      driver: local
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - backend
networks:
  backend:
    driver: $DOCKER_NETWORKS_DRIVER
```

**docker-compose.production.yml**

```yaml
services:
  mariadb:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
    environment:
      PRODUCTION: "true"
      DEBUG: "true"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DBPASSWORD_PRODUCTION
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DBNAME_PRODUCTION
      MYSQL_USER: $DBUSER_PRODUCTION
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DBPASSWORD_PRODUCTION
```

**docker-compose.development.yml**

```yaml
services:
  mariadb:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    environment:
      DEVELOPMENT: "true"
      INFO: "true"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DBPASSWORD_DEVELOPMENT
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DBNAME_DEVELOPMENT
      MYSQL_USER: $DBUSER_DEVELOPMENT
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DBPASSWORD_DEVELOPMENT
```

This starts up properly on my development machine when running:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml \
     -f docker-compose.development.yml \
     up
```

But how do I get from here to to there i.e. how can I turn this into self contained image which I can upload to my docker production host?

And where do I put it on the server so the docker production server can find it?

I think I should be able to upload and run the built image without running compose again on the production host, or shouldn't I?

For the time being, the question remains:

Why does this build command

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml \
    -f docker-compose.production.yml \
    build app
```

return **ERROR: No such service: app**?

Comment: What do your docker-compose files look like? Please include enough information in your question for us to reproduce the problem you are asking about.

Comment: [Share Compose configurations between files and projects](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) in the Docker documentation discusses multiple Compose files; but usually you wouldn't build an image on your production system or copy a `.tar.gz` file there, you'd push pre-built images to a registry (like Docker Hub or ECR) and then refer to them in the Compose setup's `image:` lines.

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand that pushing the pre built images to a registry is a widespread practice. But if understand docker properly, it's not necessary. It should be possible to deploy an Image (once it's built) to production directly. What I don't understand from your comment: If the image, being built by using compose, should once again again being referred in a compose file. I want to slap a selfcontained Application as Docker Image onto a docker server. I think that's the whole idea of Docker.

Comment: @larsks I've added the relevant declaration files. I hope this helps to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two separate issues in your question:

### How to deploy an image to the production server

To "deploy" / start a new image on a production server it needs to be downloaded with [`docker pull`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/), from a registry where it was uploaded with [`docker push`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) - i.e. you *need* a registry that is reachable from the production server and your build environment.

If you do not want to use a registry (public or private one) you can use [`docker export`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) to export an image as a tar-ball which you can manually upload to the production server and make it available with [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/).

Check [`docker image ls`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_ls/) to see if a specific image is available on your host.

But in your case I think it would be the easiest to just upload your `docker-compose.yml` and related files to the production server and directly build the images there.

---

### Why does this build command return *ERROR: No such service: app*?

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml \
    -f docker-compose.production.yml \
    build app
```

Because there is no service `app`! At least in the files you provided in your question there is only a `mariadb` service defined and no `app` service.

But starting / building the services should be the same on your local dev host and the production server.